# how to install certificates with private keys on macOS?

Tags: macos, ssl-certificate, certificate, ssh-keys

I'm trying to set up some certificates so then I can work on a web devolopment/automation project. I need to install two certs, they are .crt and .pem files. I also have a .key file to work with.
I know that in Fedora/RHEL I can do the following in order to create a system link:

`ln -s ~/appcerts /etc/pki/tls/certs/enterprise_services`

where the `appcerts` folder hold the .pem, .crt and .key file.

but I can't seem to find how to do that in MacOS. I know that I can use keychain access to setup the .crt and the .pem files, but I don't see any option to set up the .key file. I've already tried to add it with the ssh-add but that doesn't work. I'm returned wit a

`x509 error, certificate signed by unkown authority.`